# I can't check an answer - what should I do?

Tags: discussion

I created [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70504/mouse-can-still-move-but-no-clicks-are-registered-and-everything-is-locked-up) a while back.  The hard drive on that computer recently failed so I have no way of actually checking if the new solution that was proposed today would actually solve the problem.  I hadn't marked anything as the answer because there was only one other suggestion and it didn't work.  Should I just leave the question unanswered even though the proposed answer might work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's become a pseudo-policy on Ask Ubuntu, if you can't test a question anymore that it should just be closed as too localized.

You can do so by simply flagging the post for moderator attention explaining that you can no longer test this.